# Application design for bulk insert/update

Tags: postgresql, algorithm, rest, spring-batch, bulkupdate

I came across one use case where user may send bulk records through UI for Postgres table update .

1. Maximum possible record is 60,000
2. Business logic will apply some logic on the data and insert/update 8 different tables
3. There is already one Rest api which will handle one record as input and apply the same business logic and insert/update 8 different tables

What is best possible approach

**Approach 1:**
create 1 rest api which will receive the data from UI from post method and format the input record and call the existing rest api for processing . For each record call that api in parallel

**Approach 2:**
Create spring batch which will receive the data from UI( not sure how ) , write entire business logic in the process section( this is repeatable code of existing rest api )  . Use spring JPA to do the bulk insert/update using save all .

Please suggest what is the best option, or suggest is there any other better way . Sorry if this is too much information or too much I am asking .

Answer (score 0):

We proceeded with Approach 1 and it is working as expected